# Mostrar imagen con itextpdf

Tags: java, netbeans, itext

tengo una imagen en la siguiente ruta de mi proyecto  \web\resource\img\encabezado2.jpg, estoy utilizando la librería itextpdf necesito mostrar la imagen en el PDF que se crea e intentado declararla de diferentes formas pero no funciona no la encuentra.

E intentados asi :

```
Image firma = Image.getInstance("firma.JPG");
Image firma = Image.getInstance(\\resource\\img\\encabezado2.jpg)
Image firma = Image.getInstance(\encabezado2.jpg)
```

¿alguien sabe como se debe realizar y como colocar un pie de pagina?

Comment: Tu proyecto es web? Pregunto por la ruta. Y si es, es spring?

Comment: si es web esta en java 7 con MVC, jsp y servlet

Answer (score 0):

Hola debe ubicar la imagen desde el disco C:/ ejemplo:

C:/Proyecto/src/recursos/img/logo.png

Comment: Convendría agregaras una explicación